# CS-Cart price not recalculated with multiple product options

Tags: cs-cart

I am creating a new cscart store and am running into problem with products that have more than one option, which doesn't calculate the price properly.  On this [example page](http://onelifemeals.com/demo2/competitor/competitor-meal-plan.html), I have a product for which the price should change based on the meal plan and the size.  I can get one or the other to work but not both together. Thus far, I have realized that, both options are calculated from the "base" price therefore when the price is adjusted based on the meal plan, the size doesn't do anything because the "base" price is, in theory, still set to $0.00.  Any ideas on a way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways out:

1) If you set the price for one meal, for example, then both options will work, because you will have the “base” price.

2) If you set the second option in dollars, not in percents, then it will also work.

--

Maria Tainkina

CS-Cart team